# React Native's React-Navigation: Adding a badge in TabNavigator's Tab

Tags: ios, react-native, tabs, badge, react-navigation

In React-Native with React-Navigation I have a Tabnavigator like so:

```
const testScreenNavigator = TabNavigator({
    Tab1: { screen: Tab1Screen },
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2Screen },
    Tab3: { screen: Tab3Screen },
});
testScreenNavigator.navigationOptions = {
    title: 'MY TITLE',
    header: {
        titleStyle:{
        },
        style:{
// how to set the options?
        },
    }  
}
```

Now I want to add a badge next to Tab1: e.g.

### Tab1 (2)  |   Tab2   |    Tab3

In Android this can be done via:

```
 static navigationOptions = {

     tabBar: {
          label: () => {
                ... 
                return (
                   <Text style={{ backgroundColor: '...', borderRadius: 10}}>
                       {badgeNumber}
                   </Text>
                ...
```

In iOS it displays the TabMenu at the bottom, which is ok, since it is the native behavior of iOS. But in iOS the circle of the badge does not show, but a rectangular background instead.

Why is that and/or how would a Badge be done in iOS?

Regards

Comment: Did you try setting `overflow: 'hidden'`?

Comment: thx, but solved in meantime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually a badge-package in RN:
https://github.com/react-native-component/react-native-smart-badge .

Comment: Made for you :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```
import React, {Component } from 'react';
import {Animated ,Text,View,AppRegistry,Button, StyleSheet,Image } from 'react-native';

//  Badge 
export default class App extends Component {
    state = {
        badgeScale : new Animated.Value(0),
        textValue :0,
    }

    animatedBadge(){
        this.state.badgeScale.setValue(0);
        const newTextValue = ++this.state.textValue
        this.setState({textValue: newTextValue})
        Animated.timing(this.state.badgeScale , {
                toValue : 1,
                duration : 500
        }).start()
    }

    render(){
        const msize = 40;
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{ width :100, height :100, borderRadius :50, margin:10,}}>
                 <View
                            style={{ width :100, height :100, backgroundColor:'green', borderRadius :50,}}
                        /> 
                    {/* <Image
                          source={require('./circle.png')} // style={imageStyle}
                            style={{ width :100, height :100, borderRadius :50,}}
                        /> */}
                        <Animated.View style={{
                                position: 'absolute', width:msize, height:msize,
                                borderRadius:msize/2, backgroundColor:'black',
                                justifyContent:'center', alignContent:'center', 
                                borderColor:'green',borderWidth:1, 
                                // left:0, top:0,
                                left:70, top:0,     
                                // using this change bedge position 
                                    transform:[
                                        {
                                                scale:this.state.badgeScale
                                        }
                                    ]
                            }}>
                            <Text style={{backgroundColor :'transparent' ,                                  
                                            textAlign:'center',
                                        color:'red'}}>
                                    {this.state.textValue}
                            </Text>
                        </Animated.View>
                        <Button style={{ flex:1 , marginTop:50,justifyContent:'center',
                                                        alignContent:'center', }} 
                                                        title='Add' 
                                         onPress={ () =>this.animatedBadge() }>
                        </Button>                                                   
                </View>
            </View>
            );
        }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container:{
            flex:1,
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems :'center',
            // backgroundColor:'#F5FCFF'
        },
        imageStyle :{
            width:200,
            height:200,
        },
        viewTextStyle:{
            position : 'absolute',
            justifyContent:'center',
            alignItems:'center',
        },
        textStyle:{
            fontSize:23,
            fontWeight:'bold',
            color:'white'
        }
})
```